# Cannot find symbol class ScaleListener (For Pinch Zoom Feature)

Tags: java, android

While trying to code a simple pinch-zoom I encountered a configuration error that has no Google results.

I have tried putting a minimum SDK level of 8 in the manifest, tried a hundred different things. The example code has been taken from the official Android development website and a handful of StackExchange examples of implementing a touch-zoom, all of which have some code like:

```
 scaleGestureDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector( this, new ScaleListener() );
```

And every time, ScaleListener is a symbol that cannot be resolved, despite my imports being in order (as far as I can tell):

```
 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.content.Context;
 import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
 import android.graphics.Bitmap;
 import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
 import android.graphics.Canvas;
 import android.graphics.Color;
 import android.graphics.Paint;
 import android.graphics.Point;
 import android.graphics.Rect;
 import android.graphics.RectF;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.util.Log;
 import android.view.Display;
 import android.view.MotionEvent;
 import android.view.ScaleGestureDetector;
 import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
 import android.view.SurfaceView;
 import android.view.WindowManager;
```

Thanks for reading!

Comment: please add the relevant error output to your question!

Answer (score -1):

The listener [for `ScaleGestureDetector`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ScaleGestureDetector.html) is [an `OnScaleGestureListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ScaleGestureDetector.OnScaleGestureListener.html).

Comment: This is not solving my problem. I am at this point copying sample code from all across the web, all of them use new ScaleListener(), which Android Studio consistently rejects as a symbol that cannot be identified. My API is 16, and I have tried the minimum API 8 tag in the manifest.

Comment: Also OnScaleGestureListener is also a symbol that cannot be resolved. What the heck? Why is this so poorly documented? Why does a straight-up google search for the error string return NOTHING? I cannot be the only person to encounter this.

Comment: @AQuestioner: "which Android Studio consistently rejects as a symbol that cannot be identified" -- that is because there is nothing by that name in the current Android SDK. My guess is that they renamed it a few years ago. You are going to need to either use [code that is up to date](http://developer.android.com/training/gestures/scale.html#scale) or adjust your existing samples to use the now-correct listener. "Also OnScaleGestureListener is also a symbol that cannot be resolved" -- it's an inner interface of `ScaleGestureDetector`, as you can see in the documentation that I linked to.

Comment: The link you posted is one of the pages I've been using, and indeed they stipulate that I should use:  mScaleDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(context, new ScaleListener()); It is directly under the header of 'Basic scaling example' on the webpage you linked to.

Comment: @AQuestioner: That is because `ScaleListener` is defined in the code sample itself. Look down several lines from the one you quoted in your comment, and you will see `private class ScaleListener extends ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener`. `ScaleListener` is simply an example implementation of an `OnScaleGestureListener`, as part of this overall example of the use of `ScaleGestureDetector`. It is not part of the Android SDK.